# Gatling WS check does not find a match

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

I'm trying to save information from a websocket answer in an attribute. I need to wait for this, because i can't proceed the test without it. But **my check always times out**.

This is the answer from the websocket:

```
4{"cid":1337,"data":{"id":"54f81d216bae58670c070b57","isActive":true,"unreadCount":0,"sharedImages":[],"lastUpdateDate":{},"chatPartner":{"id":"5422667125d54ee17c8b4567","username":"demoUser","gender":"m","isOnline":false,"common":0,"age":25}}}
```

This is my regex pattern:

```
"\"cid\":1337,\"data\":\\{\"id\":\"(.+?)\".*"
```

This is my WScheck:

```
.check(wsAwait.within(10 seconds).until(1).regex(pattern).saveAs("conversationId"))
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I won't personally waste time on fixing your regular expression, and you shouldn't either. Gatling provides [JsonPath](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/http/http_check.html#http-response-body) based checks. With this, your check would simply be:

```
.check(wsAwait.within(10 seconds).until(1).jsonPath("$.data.id").saveAs("conversationId"))
```

Comment: Wow, you must think I'm a total noob, because you closed my github issue yesterday =D anyways: this still doesn't work. check fails because of timeout. can i debug what the ws.sendtext responds? maybe thats the issue

Comment: Just that JsonPath is way better suited for JSON than regex. :)

Comment: In order to debug the messages, try lowering logging level in logback.xml.

Comment: ok. thanks you very much! that actually helped me. thank you for showing me jsonpath

Comment: it works with my regex not not with this jsonpath. but thats fine for me